# How to run a scheduler on wildfly

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, wildfly

I'm using a scheduler for reminder. I wrote this classes to do it.

**RunWeekly.java**

```
package reminder;

public class runWeekly {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new weeklyReportService().startScheduler();
    }

}
```

**WeeklyReportService.java**

```
package reminder;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class weeklyReportService {


    public void startScheduler(){

                ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);   
                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new weeklyTask(), 0,
                        1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

    }
}
```

**weeklyTask.java**

```
package reminder;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class weeklyTask implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar with = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = with.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        String day=with.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
        if(hour==14&&day=="Monday") {
            System.out.println("Task runned at Monday 14 pm");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Task will run at Monday 14 pm");
        }
    }
}
```

I always run it as a java application but now I have to run it on wildfly server. So is that possible to run it on wildfly server?

Answer (score 1):

JavaEE support scheduling: https://www.baeldung.com/scheduling-in-java-enterprise-edition to give an example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in my situation I am currently running Jobs using JBoss wildfly by using QuartzJobBean.